# Magento 1.9.2.2 Fatal error: Call to a member function beginTransaction() on boolean on save

Tags: magento-1.9, module, database

My Magento version is 1.9.2.2. My config.xml is

```
<global>
        <models>
            <homeslider>
                <class>Transformer_HomeSlider_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>homeslider_resource</resourceModel>
            </homeslider>
            <homeslider_resource>
                <class>Transformer_HomeSlider_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <slider>
                        <table>home_slider</table>
                    </slider>
                </entities>
            </homeslider_resource>
        </models>

<resources>
    <slider_setup>
        <setup>
            <module>Transformer_HomeSlider</module>
            <class>Transformer_HomeSlider_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
        </setup>
    </slider_setup>
</resources>
    ...
    </global>
```

My Model in Models/Slider.php is

```
class Transformer_HomeSlider_Model_Slider extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('homeslider/slider');
    }
}
```

and resource file Models/Resource/Slider.php is

```
class Transformer_HomeSlier_Model_Resource_Slider extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('homeslider/slider','slider_id');
    }
}
```

My database setup script perfectly working when module run i.e table created in database. But When I want to save data on database it says

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function beginTransaction() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Abstract.php on line 313
```

I Call Model by

```
$slider_model = Mage::getModel('homeslider/slider');
```

My controller function is

```
public function saveAction()
    {
        $slider_model = Mage::getModel('homeslider/slider');
        if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {
            try {
                $slider_model->setSliderNumber($data['slider_number']);
                $slider_model->setUrlLink($data['url_link']);
                $slider_model->save();
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')
                    ->addSuccess($this->__("Your Slider has been saved"));
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')
                    ->addError($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
        $this->_redirect('*/*/edit');
    }
```

I `var_dump($data)` where I get form-data that is ok. Where is my problem? Thank you.

Comment: can you show the rest of the code where you save the slider?

Comment: I update my post with controller save function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your resource class name:

`Transformer_HomeSlier_Model_Resource_Slider` should be `Transformer_HomeSlider_Model_Resource_Slider`

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry for my Mistake. Everything is fine now.